# run two different after_create statements for different events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, callback

i have two different after_create callbacks. I only want one to run when a field is present in the created record

i have an idea of how to do it but i can't quite get the syntax

```
#rental.rb
after_create :delete_booking , :if => ":booking_no = 'NOT NULL'"
after_create :set_requires_allocation


 def delete_booking
  @booking = Booking.where(:booking_no => self.booking_no).first
 @booking.destroy
end

def set_requires_allocation
self.user.requires_allocation = 'false'
end
```

also will set_requires_allocation actually acheive what i think it will by changing 'true' to 'false' in the users table?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after_create :delete_booking, :if => Proc.new { |rental|
>   rental.booking_no.present? }

Comment: Thats worked perfectly thankyou, my self.user.requires_allocation isn't updating the record though. any ideas why?

Comment: I think you forgot save your changes, try add `self.user.save`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two `after_create` callbacks you can combine them into one line:

```
after_create :delete_booking, :set_requires_allocation, :if => Proc.new {|r| r.booking_no.present?}
```

If you want the associated user to be updated as well in the `set_requires_allocation` callback, then you might want to do something like this:

```
def set_requires_allocation
   user.update_column(:requires_allocation, false)
end
```

Just setting the attribute to false, will not actually save the user record. I chose `update_column`, since that will prevent any callbacks or validations on the User model to be triggered. If you do want to trigger callbacks on User, then use `update_attribute` (triggers callbacks, does not trigger validation checks) or `update_attributes`, which will save the user with validation checks and callbacks.